# R Shiny rows_all to return filtered rows not returning expected results

Tags: r, shiny

I've spent far too long trying to figure out how to enable the download of only the rows that I have filtered down to.  I have gotten rows_selected to work as expected but rows_all is returning the number of rows selected, but not the correct rows, i.e. instead of the rows for 'G' & 'H' the download returns 'A' & 'B'.

I created a simple app to figure out this functionality before applying it to my app.  Below is the code.

Any and all help is much appreciated!  I've posted this at reddit.com/r/rlanguage but am posting here due to the much larger audience.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

DS <- data.frame(PRODUCT = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"),
             UNITS = runif(n = 10, min = 0, max = 100),
             REVENUE = runif(n = 10, min = 1000, max = 100000))

DS <- DS %>% mutate(PRICE = REVENUE / UNITS)

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
 titlePanel("Download Selected Data Example"),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           selectInput("product",
                       "Select one of the following products:",
                       c("ALL",
                         unique(as.character(DS$PRODUCT))),
                       multiple = T))),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
  DT::dataTableOutput("ds"),
  downloadButton("downloadFiltered", "Download Filtered Rows"),
  downloadButton("downloadSelected", "Download Selected Rows")))

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
 output$ds <- DT::renderDataTable({

data <- DS

if (input$product != "ALL"){
  data <- data[data$PRODUCT %in% input$product,]
}

data

},
rownames = T,
server = F)

# download filtered rows
output$downloadFiltered <- downloadHandler(
 filename = "filteredData.csv",
 content = function(file){
   s = input$ds_rows_all
   write.csv(DS[s, , drop = F], file, row.names = T)
 })

# download selected rows
output$downloadSelected <- downloadHandler(
   filename = "selectedData.csv",
   content = function(file){
     s = input$ds_rows_selected
     write.csv(DS[s, , drop = F], file, row.names = T)
   }
  )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem arises because when downloading, you are not referencing your filtered table, but the original table, and you apply the filtered line numbers on the original table. When downloading, you need to reference your filtered table, that is possible if you store that in a reactive value and use that reactive in building the datatable AND the download:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # store the currently filtered DS in a reactive
  filteredDS <- reactive({
    if (!"ALL" %in% input$product){
      return(DS[DS$PRODUCT %in% input$product,])
    }else{
      return(DS)
    }
  })

  # display the currently filtered DS
  output$ds <- DT::renderDataTable({
    filteredDS()
  },
  rownames = T,
  server = F)

  # download filtered rows
  output$downloadFiltered <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "filteredData.csv",
    content = function(file){
      s = input$ds_rows_all
      write.csv(filteredDS()[s, , drop = F], file, row.names = T)
    })

  # download selected rows
  output$downloadSelected <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "selectedData.csv",
    content = function(file){
      s = input$ds_rows_selected
      write.csv(filteredDS()[s, , drop = F], file, row.names = T)
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  I got a similar response on reddit that I was just coming here to update with the answer when I just now saw your comment.  I really appreciate your help, this was exactly the fix!